# EC2 ping not working after moving to IPv6

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, ping

I needed an ipv6 address for my ec2 instance so I reconfigured my vpc and subnet to provide ipv6 address. I got a new ipv6 address assigned to my ec2 instance. But now ping6 to any ipv6 address like 2a03:2880:f11c:8183:face:b00c::25de from ec2 instance is not working. Moreover wget command is also not able to connect (wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/kafka/2.6.0/kafka_2.12-2.6.0.tgz). Pings to ipv4 addresses from ec2 instance are working fine. What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you show the security group rules?

Comment: Outbound rules have all traffic enabled on 0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0

Comment: Does the route table have a route to `::/0` to igw?

Comment: Adding ::/0 and 0.0.0.0/0 route to igw fixed the issue. Thanks.

Comment: That's great. No problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding ::/0 and 0.0.0.0/0 route to igw in route tables fixed the issue.